# What is the easiest way deploy java web aplication to remote tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I'm new to use Tomcat and often need to update project but I know only manually update war file on server. This is takes to much time. How can i use more effectively. I want to use git or add my remote server on eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to automate such steps. The manager-application from tomcat could be controlled by scripts. So using the manager application with some sort of script (bash, REST, ANT) would by my choice.

Take a look at:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/index.html

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html

[Tomcat manager remote deploy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432684/tomcat-manager-remote-deploy-script)

Comment: Could you send me any documentation

Comment: i have added links to my answer.